# Caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException: java.util.function.Predicate$$Lambda

Tags: scala, apache-spark

How can I make java.util.function.Predicate Serializable? Is not a class in my application, and I didn't use it everywhere, how can I fix this issue?

here is the stack

```
App > Serialization stack:
App >   - object not serializable (class: java.util.function.Predicate$$Lambda$309/931003277, value: java.util.function.Predicate$$Lambda$309/931003277@5c97826a)
App >   - field (class: io.github.resilience4j.retry.RetryConfig, name: exceptionPredicate, type: interface java.util.function.Predicate)
App >   - object (class io.github.resilience4j.retry.RetryConfig, io.github.resilience4j.retry.RetryConfig@20496d9f)
App >   - field (class: determination.resilience.GetTaxResilience, name: retryConfig, type: class io.github.resilience4j.retry.RetryConfig)
App >   - object (class determination.resilience.GetTaxResilience, determination.resilience.GetTaxResilience@af49e79)
App >   - field (class: vertex.VertexTaxComplianceOperator, name: getTaxResilience, type: class determination.resilience.GetTaxResilience)
App >   - object (class vertex.VertexTaxComplianceOperator, vertex.VertexTaxComplianceOperator@3e68a323)
App >   - field (class: vertex.VertexTaxComplianceOperator$$anonfun$5, name: $outer, type: class vertex.VertexTaxComplianceOperator)
App >   - object (class vertex.VertexTaxComplianceOperator$$anonfun$5, <function1>)
App >   - field (class: org.apache.spark.sql.execution.MapElementsExec, name: func, type: class java.lang.Object)
App >   - object (class org.apache.spark.sql.execution.MapElementsExec, MapElements <function1>, obj#512:
```

I'm so confused, this is something belong to another jar, I just use it, why I got Serialization error at this line.

```
App >   - field (class: io.github.resilience4j.retry.RetryConfig, name: exceptionPredicate, type: interface java.util.function.Predicate)
```

here is my code

```
@Component
class GetTaxResilience extends Serializable  {
    private val logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass)

    val retryConfig = RetryConfig.custom()
        .maxAttempts(RESILIENCE_RETRY_MAX_ATTEMPTS)
        .retryExceptions(classOf[StatusRuntimeException])
        .intervalFunction(IntervalFunction.ofRandomized(RESILIENCE_RETRY_INTERVAL_MILLISECONDS))
        .build

    val retryRegistry = RetryRegistry.of(retryConfig)

    val retryInstance = retryRegistry.retry(GET_VERTEX_TAX_RETRY_DEFAULT_NAME, retryConfig)

    def getDefaultRetryInstance(): Retry = {
        // default retry instance configured in yaml
        logger.info("Retrieving default retry instance: {}", GET_VERTEX_TAX_RETRY_DEFAULT_NAME)
        retryInstance
    }
}
```

Edit:

```
@Autowired
var getTaxResilience: GetTaxResilience = null

withRetry(getTaxResilience.getDefaultRetryInstance())
```

and also the error where happened is already Serializable..

```
public class RetryConfig implements Serializable
```

Edit2

```
 val calculateResultDF = preparedDataSetDF.mapPartitions(iterator => {

            val calculateResultDF = iterator.map(row => {
    //retry stuff
                )
            calculateResultDF
        }).toDF()


spark.sql(sqlBuilder.createStagingTableInsertIntoSQL(jobInfoCase.run_id)).toDF()

        insertIntoExceptionArchiveTable(spark, jobInfoCase.run_id)
```

Comment: Because with Spark, all the code that is parallelized and sent to executors needs to be serializable. Can you share how you use `GetTaxResilience` class in the Spark computation?

Comment: Hi @GaëlJ I update the code

Comment: Where is Spark involved in all this code? Why is there Spring annotations?

Comment: after retry the spark will be called, and I can't using spring here? what should I use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spark is trying to serialize the `retryConfig` field of your object.  The object in the `retryConfig` field holds a reference to something that's not serializable and which you can't make serializable.

One solution is to mark `retryConfig` `@transient`.  This will prevent it from being serialized (on the receiving end, it will be `null`).  Other `val`s which depend on a `@transient` field (in this case `retryRegistry` and, transitively, `retryInstance`) should probably also be marked `@transient`.

You would then define a `readResolve` method, which will get called on the receiving end.  This method would return a new `GetTaxResilience`, which will have appropriate values for `retryConfig`/`retryRegistry`/`retryInstance`.

```scala
class GetTaxResilience extends Serializable  {
    private val logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass)

    @transient val retryConfig = RetryConfig.custom()
        .maxAttempts(RESILIENCE_RETRY_MAX_ATTEMPTS)
        .retryExceptions(classOf[StatusRuntimeException])
        .intervalFunction(IntervalFunction.ofRandomized(RESILIENCE_RETRY_INTERVAL_MILLISECONDS))
        .build

    @transient val retryRegistry = RetryRegistry.of(retryConfig)

    @transient val retryInstance = retryRegistry.retry(GET_VERTEX_TAX_RETRY_DEFAULT_NAME, retryConfig)

    def getDefaultRetryInstance(): Retry = {
        // default retry instance configured in yaml
        logger.info("Retrieving default retry instance: {}", GET_VERTEX_TAX_RETRY_DEFAULT_NAME)
        retryInstance
    }

  private def readResolve: AnyRef = new GetTaxResilience
}
```

In this particular case, since `GetTaxResilience` takes no constructor parameters, it likely makes sense to make it an `object`, in which case it doesn't have to be made `Serializable` or have `@transient`s or a `readResolve`.

```scala
object GetTaxResilience {
    private val logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass)

    val retryConfig = RetryConfig.custom()
        .maxAttempts(RESILIENCE_RETRY_MAX_ATTEMPTS)
        .retryExceptions(classOf[StatusRuntimeException])
        .intervalFunction(IntervalFunction.ofRandomized(RESILIENCE_RETRY_INTERVAL_MILLISECONDS))
        .build

    val retryRegistry = RetryRegistry.of(retryConfig)

    val retryInstance = retryRegistry.retry(GET_VERTEX_TAX_RETRY_DEFAULT_NAME, retryConfig)

    def getDefaultRetryInstance(): Retry = {
        // default retry instance configured in yaml
        logger.info("Retrieving default retry instance: {}", GET_VERTEX_TAX_RETRY_DEFAULT_NAME)
        retryInstance
    }
}
```

Then in Scala code to access the default retry instance, you just need:

```scala
GetTaxResilience.getDefaultRetryInstance()
```

(though the more Scala-idiomatic way would just be `GetTaxResilience.retryInstance`)